# How do I disable merged CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, cache, core-config-data, merge-css

I merged CSS and/or JavaScript and my website is all messed up.

How do I disable the CSS/JS merge functions?

It's so messed up I can't access the Admin panel, how do I do it in the database?

Answer (score 16):

go to `database` and execute this `query`

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'dev%'
```

change these value from **`1`** to **`0`**

```
dev/js/merge_files
dev/css/merge_css_files
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have access to the Admin backend, navigate to the following configuration and set both CSS and JS merge to `No` and save config

`System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Developer`

Also check to make sure you haven't set up separate configuration scopes for this (arrow - upper right corner)

[image]

Then clear your Magento cache and the CSS and JS merge caches (buttons at bottom)

[image]

To manually do the above via database edits and manual cache clearing:

The settings for the CSS/JS merge are stored in the `core_config_data` table with the following paths. Use phpMyAdmin or the command line to change their values from 1 to 0

```
dev/js/merge_files
dev/css/merge_css_files
```

Flush the Magento cache by deleting all the `mage--?` sub-directories in `var/cache/` so Magento's configuration settings will be reloaded.

The merge files for CSS and JS are stored in the following Magento directories, manually delete the contents of these folders.

```
media/js/
media/css/
```

NOTE: If flushing the Magento cache does not allow the config change to update, you may have the following issue: [Can't change Magento config, stuck in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947825/722112)